# laravel 5.3 auth always redirect to login page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to create authentication on laravel, but i have a problem.
when i want to access another page, the page has redirected to login page.

Here is my routes

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/news/getid/{id_category}', 'NewsController@getid');
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {
    Route::resource('news', 'NewsController', ['except' => ['getid']]);
    Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
});
```

and here is my LoginController

```
protected $redirectTo = '/news';

public function username()
{
    return 'username';
}

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

Comment: if you try to access the routes under auth middleware group, you'll be redirected to login page, if not logged in.

Comment: Is user authenticated? if not, as @SanzeebAryal said, it's the expected behaviour. Or do you want the user to be redirected to the wanted page after login?

Comment: hi @SanzeebAryal. I've been logged in, but when i want to access another page, the page just redirected to login page again. it's just like my session was not remembered.

Answer (score 2):

You have to comment **$this->middleware('auth');** line from constructor of your "NewsController". It should be

```
public function __construct()
{
// $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

**Note:** By commenting this line, Never check authentication for all view page that return from this controller.

Comment: hi :)
but there's no that function on my controller.

Comment: So how is your authentication working ? Are you worked at route file for authentication?

Comment: yes, i'm working at route file using this `Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () {`.
I've been try using `$this->middleware('auth');` on my controller like you mentioned, but it still same

Comment: Are you tried with laravel default authentication? if yes please give me the screenshot / code of your route file.

Answer (score 0):

`Route::auth();` should be in `web` middleware group as auth routes use session to remember logged in user.

Comment: i've been try to put `Route::auth()` inside of web middleware group, but i'm getting this error on my chrome browser `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove this line in every page that you don't want to be protected by the authentication:

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

so basically remove it from the "another page"s controller that you mentioned above.

Comment: hi :)
but there's no `$this->middleware('auth');` on my controller.

Answer (score 0):

In your Route file(Maybe web.php). Remove the auth middleware from the group
Like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web' , 'auth']], function () {
Route::resource('news', 'NewsController', ['except' => ['getid']]);
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
});
```

to become like this:

```
Route::group('middleware' => 'web', function () {
Route::resource('news', 'NewsController', ['except' => ['getid']]);
Route::resource('category', 'CategoryController');
});
```

But be sure you really don't need to protect that route.